# Tor Browser doesn't work due to no access to control port

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I try to connect on Tor, but I always got the same message "Something Went Wrong!" 
It appears after deleting the previous version (3.x) to the new one (4.x) 
When I try to change my identity it's written

> Torbutton cannot safely give you a new identity. It does not have access to the Tor Control Port. Are you running Tor Browser Bundle?

I really don't know from where it comes.

I've already try to unistall/reinstall the Tor Browser Bundle (like 10/15 times), and it always come.
Sometimes, I can connect (like 1 time every 5 try)
What can I do?

```
30/11/2014 22:51:24.110 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.110 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.110 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\TBB2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.540 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.619 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.795 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
30/11/2014 22:51:24.951 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
30/11/2014 22:51:25.110 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
30/11/2014 22:51:26.359 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
30/11/2014 22:51:26.792 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
30/11/2014 22:51:27.276 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:27.276 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6748, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of exit bw.) 
30/11/2014 22:51:27.598 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:30.862 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 55%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:31.519 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 60%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:32.394 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 65%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:33.301 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 70%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:33.473 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 75%: Loading relay descriptors 
30/11/2014 22:51:34.608 [NOTICE] We now have enough directory information to build circuits. 
30/11/2014 22:51:34.608 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
30/11/2014 22:51:34.609 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit 
30/11/2014 22:51:35.151 [NOTICE] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working. 
30/11/2014 22:51:35.151 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100%: Done 
30/11/2014 22:51:42.877 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
```

Comment: Have you tried to install TBB into a new directory andstart it from there?

Comment: Once use Adwcleaner it erase unwanted data from ur PC, might help.

Comment: The question is now more than eight months old and never received an answer to comments from the OP. So I decided to close it. Whenever the OP comes back and gives some advise what he did, it can be reopened and answered.